# Bash script - splitting .TAR file in smaller parts

Tags: mysql, bash, backup, tar, dropbox

this a part of a .sh script I need to edit to make some backups and upload them on Dropbox but I need to split that backup in smaller parts.

```
NOW=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d")
DESTFILE="$BACKUP_DST/$NOW.tgz"

# Backup mysql.
mysqldump -u $MYSQL_USER -h $MYSQL_SERVER -p$MYSQL_PASS --all-databases > "$NOW-Databases.sql"
tar cfz "$DESTFILE" "$NOW-Databases.sql"
```

And then the function to upload the backup on DropBox....

```
dropboxUpload "$DESTFILE"
```

How can I split the .tar file in smaller parts (for example of 100 or 200mb size) and get the name and the number of those files to upload them with the dropboxUpload function?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`split`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html). For example, this:

```
split -b500k $DESTFILE ${DESTFILE}-
```

will split `$DESTFILE` into 500 KB pieces called:

```
${DESTFILE}-aa
${DESTFILE}-ab
${DESTFILE}-ac
...
```

Then you could loop through them with something like:

```
for x in ${DESTFILE}-*
do
    dropboxUpload $x
end
```

Comment: How can I join them on windows to extract after that?

Comment: @Mark: I think you'd use `copy /a parts... dest` but my Windows knowledge is rather weak.

Answer (score 0):

To join binary files in windows, use

```
copy /b parts.. dest
```

/a is for ASCII text files.

Comment: this has nothing really to do with the original question.